# Just can't import EasyDict on anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

I am trying to run a project using a virtual environment on anaconda (created using the `.yml` file), everything looks fine but for some reason `"EasyDict"` just can't be imported.

```
from easydict import EasyDict as edict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easydict'
```

These are the things i already tried:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/auto easydict
conda install easydict -c conda-forge
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 easydict
conda install easydict
pip install easydict
```

the strange thing is that it is obviously imported, since in Visual Code it recognizes it, and the file exists in the virtual environment.

Comment: Are you running the code with same conda environment that you installed easydict into?

Comment: Yes, I already checked that